# How to restore data from previous Prometheus container data?

Tags: docker, prometheus

I had a running prometheus container that was storing data in `/var/lib/docker/prometheus`. However after I made changes in docker-compose file and restarted the container it started storing new data in `/var/lib/docker/prometheus/data` due to which I lost all my previous timeseries data. I tried to restore existing data by copying data from outer `/prometheus` directory to `/prometheus/data`, but it didn't work. Please help.
I added below lines to my docker-compose.yml:

```
command: 
   --storage.tsdb.retention.time=90d 
   --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Comment: for working with persisting data, you need to use [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)

Comment: @LucasBazetto , I've already mounted volume to the container. Seems like the default data directory changed in the recent version. Fixing older version tag on the image fixed the issue for me.